# How to use JSTL tag in AJAX jQuery tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem in our Spring MVC project, I want to get value from MODEL class using JSTL under AJAX jQuery tag.

Comment: <c:forEach items="${mylistnew}" var="notices" varStatus="loop"><td style="vertical-align:middle;font-size:16px">${notices.date_value}</td> </c:forEach>

Comment: Couldn't get your question.Can you give any example?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the jQuery code in a jsp file (instead of a js file) and use the jstl tag inside js code. You can import the jsp file where you are importing all other js files